# How to set data-* from datasources in Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select2 as follow:

```
$('select#fields').select2({
   placeholder: 'Select a field',
   data: data.fields
});
```

`data.fields` is a JSON like this one:

```
"fields": [
  {
    "id": "companies_id",
    "text": "companies_id",
    "data-type": "int"
  },
  {
    "id": "parent_companies_id",
    "text": "parent_companies_id",
    "data-type": "int"
  },
  {
    "id": "client_of_companies_id",
    "text": "client_of_companies_id",
    "data-type": "int"
  },
  {
    "id": "asset_locations_id",
    "text": "asset_locations_id",
    "data-type": "int"
  },
  {
    "id": "companies_name",
    "text": "companies_name",
    "data-type": "varchar"
  },
  {
    "id": "companies_number",
    "text": "companies_number",
    "data-type": "varchar"
  }
]
```

`id` and `text` are used to fill the option values, can I use the third value `data-type` and set it as an attribute for the `<option>`? If so how? Can any leave me an example?

Comment: Might try something with the [templating](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating).

Comment: @lamelemon, actually no templating is required here. You can check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually - select2 by default saves all of the attributes in the `data('data')` variable of the `<option>` element that it creates, and you can always access these values using the `$(<option>).data('data')`, however keep in mind that **it's not** the same as `.data('type')` for `data-type="value"`. You need to use the complete name of the attribute.

Here is an example of how to get the value of `data-type` on `select` event:

```js
var $example = $("#s1").select2({
    data: [
        {
            "id": "companies_id",
            "text": "companies_id",
            "data-type": "int",
            "data-extra": '1'
        },
        {
            "id": "parent_companies_id",
            "text": "parent_companies_id",
            "data-type": "int",
            "data-extra": '2'
        },
        {
            "id": "client_of_companies_id",
            "text": "client_of_companies_id",
            "data-type": "int",
            "data-extra": '3'
        },
        {
            "id": "asset_locations_id",
            "text": "asset_locations_id",
            "data-type": "int",
            "data-extra": '4'
        },
        {
            "id": "companies_name",
            "text": "companies_name",
            "data-type": "varchar",
            "data-extra": '5'
        },
        {
            "id": "companies_number",
            "text": "companies_number",
            "data-type": "varchar",
            "data-extra": '6'
        }
    ],
}).on('select2:select', function(e) {
    console.log(e.params.data['data-type'], e.params.data['data-extra']);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
</select>
```

Comment: I already voted up ;) although this is more complicated than I though and I will open a new topic, hope you can help me as well

Comment: Post the link to the new topic

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383852/how-to-read-dynamic-data-from-one-select-to-the-other-using-select2) and thx in advance