# how to get the data-* value of a selected option in select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

This is like a second part of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381211/how-to-set-data-from-datasources-in-select2) and right now I need to be able to read dynamic `data-*` properties from one select to the other. What this mean?

First take a look to the following image:

[image]

What you're seeing there is what the following code does:

```
// This turn 1st and 3rd into select2
$('#module, #conditions').select2();

// This turn 2nd into select2 using data from a datasource
$('select#fields').select2({
   placeholder: 'Select a field',
   data: data.fields
});
```

As I posted in the referenced topic the `data.fields` has a JSON like the following:

```
"fields": [
  {
    "id": "companies_id",
    "text": "companies_id",
    "data-type": "int"
  },
  {
    "id": "parent_companies_id",
    "text": "parent_companies_id",
    "data-type": "int"
  },
  {
    "id": "client_of_companies_id",
    "text": "client_of_companies_id",
    "data-type": "int"
  },
  {
    "id": "asset_locations_id",
    "text": "asset_locations_id",
    "data-type": "int"
  },
  {
    "id": "companies_name",
    "text": "companies_name",
    "data-type": "varchar"
  },
  {
    "id": "companies_number",
    "text": "companies_number",
    "data-type": "varchar"
  }
]
```

In this case I need to read the `data-*` attributes assigned to the 2nd select (field) from the `onChange()` event on the 3rd select (conditions) and then make some modifications to the INPUT (but this is on me).

How can I get the `data-*` values from any of the other select2 elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is more of "how to get the `data-*` value of a selected option in select2?".

Check this example:

```js
var $example = $("#s1").select2({
  data: [
    {
      "id": "companies_id",
      "text": "companies_id",
      "data-type": "int",
      "data-extra": '1'
    },
    {
      "id": "parent_companies_id",
      "text": "parent_companies_id",
      "data-type": "int",
      "data-extra": '2'
    },
    {
      "id": "client_of_companies_id",
      "text": "client_of_companies_id",
      "data-type": "int",
      "data-extra": '3'
    },
    {
      "id": "asset_locations_id",
      "text": "asset_locations_id",
      "data-type": "int",
      "data-extra": '4'
    },
    {
      "id": "companies_name",
      "text": "companies_name",
      "data-type": "varchar",
      "data-extra": '5'
    },
    {
      "id": "companies_number",
      "text": "companies_number",
      "data-type": "varchar",
      "data-extra": '6'
    }
  ],
}).on('select2:select', function(e) {
  console.log(e.params.data['data-type'], e.params.data['data-extra']);
});
$('button').click(function() {
  option_el = $('#s1 :selected');
  data = option_el.data('data')
  
  console.log(data['data-type'])
  console.log(data['data-extra'])
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
</select>
<br />
<br />
<button>Click to the the `data-type` value</button>
```

Comment: Hi @Dekel can you help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386965/can-not-trigger-an-ajax-call-into-element-turned-in-a-select2) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388162/cant-make-select2-work-when-element-is-inside-a-jquery-ui-modal) as well? I am stuck on them and don't know what I am doing wrong and maybe the issue is the same

Comment: I'll try to have a look